# Login only prestashop catalog

Tags: customization, prestashop

Im building a prestashop catalog, but it needs to be visible to logged in customers only. Is this possible. It would be nice if the built in prestashop login is used for this.. any help is appreciated.

Comment: this might work its expensive though :( [link](http://www.presto-changeo.com/en/prestashop-modules/30-private-shop.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be easy.

Use this code:

```
 if(!self::$cookie->isLogged(true) AND in_array($this->step, array(1, 2, 3)))
    Tools::redirect('authentication.php');
```

In the preprocess of your indexController

Comment: thanks, got it working without the in_array() part, w what does it mean btw?

Comment: one more thing, this only works when a customer visits the homepage, and all other pages work visited through a direct link

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion. You can use the Customer Groups feature in PrestaShop 1.5 and only  allow logged in customers to see the prices. For every Customer that is grouped in Visitor, they would see your website in Catalog Mode.

Answer (score 2):

Prestashop 1.5 solution:

Simply upload the original file:

```
classes\controller\FrontController.php
```

into:

```
override/classes/controller/FrontController.php
```

Next, rename the class.  Final code should look like this:

```
class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        if (!$this->context->customer->isLogged() && $this->php_self != 'authentication' && $this->php_self != 'password')
        {
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication?back=my-account');
        }
    }
}
```

The last step is to manually delete the following file so prestashop is aware of the overriden class (It will be re-generated automatically):

```
cache/class_index.php
```

And voilà, functionality achieved without overwriting core files.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s my solution, it works like a charm and is a very easy fix!

In classes\Configuration.php (around line 114) it looks like this

```
static public function get($key, $id_lang = NULL)
{
    if ($id_lang AND isset(self::$_CONF_LANG[(int)$id_lang][$key]))
        return self::$_CONF_LANG[(int)$id_lang][$key];
    elseif (is_array(self::$_CONF) AND key_exists($key, self::$_CONF))
        return self::$_CONF[$key];
    return false;
}
```

change it to this:

```
static public function get($key, $id_lang = NULL)
{
    //Grab access to the $cookie which is already loaded in the FrontController as global $cookie;
    global $cookie;
    if ($id_lang AND isset(self::$_CONF_LANG[(int)$id_lang][$key]))
        return self::$_CONF_LANG[(int)$id_lang][$key];
    elseif (is_array(self::$_CONF) AND key_exists($key, self::$_CONF))
        //If the system is trying to find out if Catalog Mode is ON, then return the configuration setting,
        //but override it with the user logon status
        if($key == 'PS_CATALOG_MODE')
        {
            return !$cookie->logged || self::$_CONF[$key];
        }
        else
        {
            return self::$_CONF[$key];
        }
    return false;
}
```

Essentially, I wanted to force the system to display the “Catalog Mode” when the user is not logged in, and to turn this off when he is logged in.

I can guarantee this works for v1.4.3.0 and the code for the current version 1.4.8.2 (at the time of this post) has not changed, so it should work there.

Comment: thanks a lot, earlier solution only works for the index/ home page, putting it in the configuration makes more sense!

Comment: I want to take people to authentication.php if they are not logged in, and not show the catalog mode or anything until logged in.

Comment: Great answer ! Thank you for sharing.